# How can I use paint?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I'm trying to use paint on mobile terraria (pink). But when I apply it to my wood some of it is pink but some turns out blue. I've used blue paint on those same blocks but I've also used a paint scraper to get rid of the paint but when I apply more pink paint it turns out blue (trying to make Transpride Flag).

How can I reliably use pink paint?

Answer (score -1):

I think that is a bug. I tried to use pink paint it works fine but maybe it matters what wood your using. If you just use an oak wall and try to troubleshoot the problem you might find out if it is a glitch or the game doesn't allow that wood to be dyed a certain color.